# Grails: Batching client requests - invoke one controller from another

Tags: grails

We have a large Grails app and we'd like to batch some of the client side GET requests into a single request. This is pretty easy, we can easily make a JSON request like this:

```
[{
    "id": "req1",
    "url": "whatever",
    "params": { "id": 1 }
}, {
    "id": "req2",
    "url": "another",
    "params": { "name": "Bob" }
}]
```

And send it to some Grails controller, let's say `BatchController.processBatch`. Ideally, `BatchController` would:

1. Determine which controller and action the URL maps to (via URLMappings somehow)
2. Invoke that method, adding the methods response to the single large response object.
3. Finally, render the single response object.

So the response might look something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "req1": {
        "data": ...
        "success": true
    },
    "req2": {
        "data": ...
        "success": true
    }
}
```

So, first, I'm not sure how I would handle #1 (determining the controller and action/method). Second, I'm concerned about the Controller lifecycle since I'm now invoking the controllers myself instead of letting Grails handle it.

Any advice would be helpful. Has anyone done anything like this before?